# How can I provide delay between dependent API calls dynamically in JMeter script

Tags: jmeter, performance, load-testing, tools, api

I want to create JMeter script in which some API calls are made only after the response to the API calls which it is dependent upon is received successfully. Is it possible in JMeter? And if yes then please let me know how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To determine whether previous sampler was successful or not you can use [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-if-controller-and-get-pie) and the following condition:

   ```
   ${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok}
   ```

   Something like:

   - Request 1
   - If Controller with the above condition

     - Request 2
   - Request 3

   Assuming the above configuration `Request 2` will be executed only if `Request 1` is successful. `Request 3` will be executed always
2. In regards to adding a delay between requests there are 2 ways:

   - [Test Action](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Action) sampler in `Pause` mode. It doesn't generate sample result and you can use it for pausing thread(s) between request
   - JMeter provides variety of [Timers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#timers). Timers respect [scoping rules](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules) and produce delay **before** sampler(s) in scope is(are) executed.